# Elastalert is not alerting with Slack channel

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elastalert

I am setting up the Elastalert alert system with Slack.

Here is the Elastalert config.

```
s_host: localhost
es_port: 9200
name: Slack rule
type: frequency
index: filebeat-*
num_events: 1
timeframe:
  minutes: 1
filter:
- term:
    msg: "proper name is required"
alert:
- "slack"
slack_webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/SSDFRD/SDDDDS/XXXSDDDSDDDDDDDSS"
slack_channel_override: "#kibana"
slack_username_override: "@anand"
```

Getting below error

```
ERROR:root:Error finding recent pending alerts: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'No mapping found for [alert_time] in order to sort on') 

{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":{
            "query_string":{
               "query":"!_exists_:aggregate_id AND alert_sent:false"
            }
         },
         "filter":{
            "range":{
               "alert_time":{
                  "from":"2020-08-25T13:33:31.764880Z",
                  "to":"2020-08-27T13:33:31.764901Z"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "sort":{
      "alert_time":{
         "order":"asc"
      }
   }
}
```

Elasticsearch record

```
{
_index: "filebeat-log",
_type: "doc",
_id: "m3DVLnQBAkDXq2X4hDio",
_score: 1,
_source: {
time: "2020-08-27T07:32:58.075Z",
msg: "proper name is required",
name: "myApp",
v: 0,
@timestamp: "2020-08-27T07:32:59.048Z",
host: "AMM00361",
pid: 5026,
level: 50,
hostname: "AMM00361",
type: "myApp",
@version: "1",
path: "/var/log/myapp-error.log"
}
}
```

After running the Elastalert service I couldn't get the alert message in Slack.

Please share your thoughts!

Comment: change alert_time to @timestamp . es doesn't find the field alert_time in your mapping

Comment: thanks for the update. How to update with ES